# How to use OSAtomicCompareAndSwapPtrBarrier from Swift?

Tags: concurrency, swift, atomic

I have already asked this question in the official [Apple developer forums](https://devforums.apple.com/thread/236101?tstart=30), but unfortunately did not get an answer. I am currently trying to build some simple concurrent data structures in Swift and couldn't find a way to call `OSAtomicCompareAndSwapPtrBarrier` from Swift code. The signature is

```
OSAtomicCompareAndSwapPtrBarrier(
  __oldValue: UnsafePointer<()>,
  __newValue: UnsafePointer<()>,
  __theValue: UnsafePointer<UnsafePointer<()>>)
```

which in C would be

```
OSAtomicCompareAndSwapPtrBarrier(
  void *__oldValue,
  void *__newValue,
  void * volatile *__theValue)
```

I couldn't find a way to create an `UnsafePointer<UnsafePointer<()>>`. Just a short code example:

```
class Stack<A> {
  var __head: Node<A>

  init() {
    __head = Node()
  }

  func push(elem: A) {
    var newNode = Node<A>()
    newNode.elem = elem
    var currentHead: Node<A>
    do {
      currentHead = __head
      newNode.next = currentHead
    } while(!OSAtomicCompareAndSwapPtrBarrier(&currentHead, &newNode, &__head))
  }
}

class Node<A> {
  var elem: A?
  var next: Node<A>?
}
```

Using `&__head`obviously does not work, as it only creates an `UnsafePointer<()>`. So how can I create the `UnsafePointer<UnsafePointer<()>>` here?

**edit**:

In C I can use it as follows (I don't normally use C, so this code may be terribly wrong):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <libkern/OSAtomic.h>

typedef struct {
  int bar;
} foo;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
  // insert code here...
  foo * volatile f = malloc(sizeof(foo));
  foo *n = malloc(sizeof(foo));

  f->bar = 1;
  foo *old = f;
  n->bar = 3;

  OSAtomicCompareAndSwapPtrBarrier(old, n, &f);

  free(old);
  printf("%d\n", f->bar);
  free(f);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try `&&__head`.. You need to pass a pointer to `&__head` and this should do it...

Comment: This also does not work. `&&__head` gives "'&&' is not a prefix unary operator" and `&(&__head)` gives "inout Node<A> is not a subtype of '@lvalue $T28'"

Comment: how do you use it in C?

Comment: updated my question with some C code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example how to use OSAtomicCompareAndSwapPtrBarrier or OSAtomicCompareAndSwapPtr in Swift:

```
public final class AtomicReference<T : AnyObject> {
    private var _value : T
    public var value : T {
        get {
            OSMemoryBarrier()
            return _value
        }
        set {
            OSMemoryBarrier()
            _value = newValue
        }
    }

    private let pointer : UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>> = UnsafeMutablePointer.alloc(1)
    public init(_ value : T) {
        self._value = value
        pointer.memory = UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>(Unmanaged.passUnretained(value).toOpaque())
    }
    deinit {
        pointer.destroy()
    }

    public func compareAndSwap(#oldValue : T, newValue: T) -> Bool {
        let ov = Unmanaged.passUnretained(oldValue)
        let nv = Unmanaged.passUnretained(newValue)

        if OSAtomicCompareAndSwapPtrBarrier(UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>(ov.toOpaque()), UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>(nv.toOpaque()), pointer) {
            _value = newValue
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

This code is a class which works like AtomicReference in Java. It enables you to avoid thread locks in some cases using atomic operations instead. Atomic operations usually provide higher performance in case of high concurrency.

The compareAndSwap function will change the value only if the previous value is the same as oldValue. For instance:

```
class LockArray {
    var value = NSArray()
    let lock = NSLock()
    func addItem(item : Int) {
        lock.lock()
        value = value.arrayByAddingObject(item)
        lock.unlock()
    }
}

class AtomicArray {
    let reference = AtomicRefence<NSArray>([])
    func addItem(item : Int) {
        while true {
            let oldValue = reference.value
            let newValue = oldValue.arrayByAddingObject(item)
            if reference.compareAndSwap(oldValue: oldValue, newValue: newValue) {
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Both of these classes are thread-safe and do the same thing. However, the second one will work better with high concurrency.

Comment: It'd be nice a brief explanation on the main points of what the code does :)

Comment: I have added an explanation.

Comment: And that's why you get a +1 from me

Comment: This code assumes that assignments to (and loads from) _value are atomic, which isn't necessarily the case. Also, _value may be set to an outdated value when two calls to compareAndSwap are interleaved, breaking CAS semantics.

Comment: @Fnord You are right, this implementation is not fully correct but I put it here only as an example of using OSAtomicCompareAndSwapPtr. I think it serves this purpose. By the way, do you now a proper implementation of AtomicReference? It is not so easy to implement due to reference counting.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var pointer = UnsafePointer< UnsafePointer< Node<A> > >.alloc(1)
pointer.initialize(&__head)
```

This explicitly allocates the pointer and fills it.

PS: Donot forget to call `pointer.dealloc(1)` after you are done with it...

EDIT: You might have to create an `UnsafePointer< Node<A> >` similar to the above explicitly instead of using `&__head` and pass it to `initialize` instead...

Comment: This compiles, but the CAS always fails, so the two pointers are always different. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

**You can also try this.**

- Just open your Podfile.lock.
- Find 'Protobuf'.
- Change version of 'Protobuf (xx.xx.xx) to Protobuf (3.21.12).
- Run 'pod install' command in terminal.

*I was facing this issue with Xcode 14.3.*